# CakePHP load model validation rule not working

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

I am loading a model in different controller.
Controller name in which I am loading different model is - "MembersController" and I am loading "Usermgmt" Model of "UsermgmtController".
"Usermgmt" Model has validation as following-

```
public $validate = array(
        'email' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Please enter a value for email.'
            ),
            'duplicate' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'on' => 'create',
                'message' => 'This email is already exist.'
            ),
            'duplicate1' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Please enter valid email.'
            )
        ),
        'firstname' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Please enter a value for first name.'
            )
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Please enter a value for user name.'
            ),
            'duplicate' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'on' => 'create',
                'message' => 'This user is already exist.'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Please enter a value for password.'
            )
        ),
        'confirm_password' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Please enter a value for confirm password.'
            ),
            'duplicate2' => array(
                'rule' => 'matchpassword',
                'on' => 'create',
                'message' => 'Password must be same.'
            )
        )
    );
```

And now I am applying and loading model in following way.

```
$this->loadModel('Usermgmt');
            $this->Usermgmt->set($this->data);

            if ($this->Usermgmt->validates()) {
  if ($this->Usermgmt->save($data, true)) {
                    $userid = $this->Usermgmt->id;

                    $this->Session->setFlash('User has been added', 'success');

                }
}
```

But validation are not working and it is inserting empty values.

Answer (score 0):

try `uses` to load model

Example :

```
public $uses = array('Usermgmt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different instances of `$data`. namely `$this->data` and `$data`

You should be validating the same set of data you want to save, like either of the two following examples, whichever holds your data.

```
$this->loadModel('Usermgmt');
        $this->Usermgmt->set($data);

        if ($this->Usermgmt->validates()) {
if ($this->Usermgmt->save($data, true)) {
                $userid = $this->Usermgmt->id;

                $this->Session->setFlash('User has been added', 'success');

            }
```

}

Or

```
$this->loadModel('Usermgmt');
        $this->Usermgmt->set($this->data);

        if ($this->Usermgmt->validates()) {
if ($this->Usermgmt->save($this->data, true)) {
                $userid = $this->Usermgmt->id;

                $this->Session->setFlash('User has been added', 'success');

            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are requiring to do some other logic after validation and before saving you could do away with explicitly calling `validates()` and just save the data as `save()` will automatically validate the data for you. Also, I've noticed you are using `$this->data`, it looks like you are using CakePHP 2 in which case you need to use `$this->request->data` instead:-

```
$this->loadModel('Usermgmt');

if ($this->Usermgmt->save($this->request->data) !== false) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('User has been added', 'success');
}
```

If this still fails then make sure you are not overriding `beforeValidate()` in your model in a way that would cause validation to break.